# What is the best way to deal with a school program that is rife with academic dishonesty?

Tags: cheating

Several years ago, I was employed at a Federal lab. It was a good job but had a lot of nonsense from certain employees.

The lab offered a graduate program through a major university. I was interested and actually enrolled in a class. However, my interests quickly changed. It changed because in the class I was enrolled in, a fellow employee showed up with a notebook that contained all of the assignments, and even old tests issued by the professor. Oddly, his name was not on any of the assignments but someone else's name was who once worked there but left. As well, I asked him where he got the binder and he told another employee (not the one listed on the tests/assignments) gave it to him. I was so turned off, I dropped the class: I had no interests in getting a degree like that. As well, I asked around and I found out that this was not an isolated incident.

I was wondering, if someone on here could tell me, if that university's credentialing is at risk because of cheating in that program?

I was advised that once that if a university didn't take cheating allegations seriously then its credentials could be in jeopardy.

Comment: Sharing past assignments or exams is not necessarily cheating, unless the professor explicitly forbade it.  In my experience, professors usually consider that it is perfectly fine for students to look at past assignments or exams as a way to study, and they design their classes accordingly (e.g. by not reusing exam questions from one year to the next).

Comment: @NateEldredge, that is, at least, the core of an answer.

Comment: @Buffy: Well, maybe OP could clarify whether they have some specific reason to believe that this behavior was actually forbidden, or if that's just an assumption, or if they personally consider it dishonest whether it's against the rules or not.

Comment: What you describe could be an issue if the Professor always gives the same assignments and solutions, but if that is the case, the Prof is NOT doing his job properly. But if the assignments and exams are prepared properly, what you describe should not be an issue, looking at those matrials would be no different than looking at some examples in the textbook.

Comment: Further to what Nate Eldredge wrote, I suspect that every fraternity and sorority house in the United States has fat binders full of old material.  At least one program at the university from which I retired posts old quizzes and exams on the program's "resources" web page.

Comment: You have one example. So "rife with ..." is an overstatement. The example may be valid or not as others here have mentioned. To assume it is valid, you have to also assume that this is a violation, but ignored in some way.

Comment: I suggest deleting the example from the question as it is distracting from what you are asking.

Comment: Here is an example of what happens to the university.  Mostly they just loose reputation.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/University_of_North_Carolina_academic-athletic_scandal

Answer (score 7):

> I had no interests in getting a degree like that.

A degree like *what*? From your description as of the current edit, you have no evidence that cheating is going on. Not all instructors have a problem with students using old exam and assignment material from previous years. Some will even regard it as beneficial and actively allow their old materials to be reused. Whether cheating occurred or not is highly context dependent - context that you have not provided in the question.

Your question about how to deal with rife cheating is simply premature. My suggestion is, first find out whether cheating is actually occurring and what is the extent of it. Then share your findings and we will be able to discuss what kinds of consequences the program is at risk of suffering and what if anything can be done.